# fatal error: 'AWSHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 'server_hostname'

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terminal

I get this error when running `awscli` (e.g. I try to run `aws s3 sync --delete $BUCKET_URI $PUB_KEYS_DIR` I get this).

I have tried reinstalling (`apt-get remove awscli && apt-get update && apt-get install awscli`), but it doesn't help.

I don't understand where this `server_hostname` is specified?

Also, this `aws s3...` command worked before and then just stopped working at some moment.

Comment: maybe the value of `$BUCKET_URI` is not valid anymore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That error is probably related to the fact that you have used `apt-get install` to install `awscli`.

Try to remove it

```
sudo apt-get remove awscli
```

and reinstall it with `pip`

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade awscli
```

If that doesn't work, then you can try to install it using aws bundler installer.

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"

unzip awscli-bundle.zip

sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

I forgot to add in the question that I also tried using `pip install awscli`, but it didn't help. 

Now, when using `pip install --upgrade awscli` it works.